# Facing issue with setting value for dropdown list from Model

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I am using MVC with KnockoutJs and facing an issue with a `value` binding.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PrimarySubspecialty, Model.PrimarySubspecialties, new { id = "ddUserDetailsPrimarySubSpeciality", style = "width:245px;height:25px;", @class = "nmc-select", data_bind = "options: primarySubSpecialities,optionsText: 'Name',optionsValue: 'Id',value:PrimarySubspecialty" })
```

I am not sure why the `PrimarySubspecialty` value in the model is not getting bound to the dropdown selected value.

Here is my js code:

```
this.PrimarySubspecialty = Ko.observable($('#ddUserDetailsPrimarySubSpeciality').val());
this.primarySubSpecialities = ko.observableArray([]);

function loadPrimarySubSpecilaities() { 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: primarySubSpecialityUrl,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        processdata: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {

            primarySubSpecialities = [];

            try {
                if (data.length == 0) {

                    primarySubSpeacilityDropdownId.empty();

                }
                model.primarySubSpecialities(data);
            }
    });
}
```

Please let me know how I can set the value to `PrimarySubSpeciality` dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

When using asynchronous methods to fill dropdown or select lists you have to be careful to avoid binding the selected value **before** the list has been filled.

If you change a list, Knockout will only retain the bound value if it exists in the list. If it does not, the value will be set as *undefined*.

To correct your code, save the value in a variable and only set the observable *after* the list is filled:

```
var holdingValue = $('#ddUserDetailsPrimarySubSpeciality').val();
this.PrimarySubspecialty = Ko.observable();
```

Then set the value once the list is filled:

```
model.primarySubSpecialities(data);
model.PrimarySubspecialty(holdingValue);
```

I've done a quick JSFiddle test page to demonstrate this: https://jsfiddle.net/Quango/0bxaqLf8/